Relation between the damping ratio and the phase margin in 2nd order systems
I can't remember how to derive the relation between the damping ratio $\zeta$ and the phase margin. I cant remember where to start from to end up with a numerical relationship between them for a general case.
I remember reading about this many years ago in the book I used in university by Kuo, and I was reminded of this relation in a completely different context, and wanted to find this derivation but couldn't find it.
Can someone remind me where to start to derive this relationship, and remind me the final relationship expression for a general 2nd order system case?

Even though Dan's answer is well written and everything in it looks correct, I believe that the original question remains unanswered, namely the relation between the phase margin and the damping of a second-order system.
In order to compute the phase margin we need the open-loop transfer function $G(s)$. Starting with the closed-loop transfer function
$$H(s)=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}=\frac{\omega_n}{D(s)}\tag{1}$$
and the well-known relation
$$H(s)=\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}\tag{2}$$
we obtain
$$G(s)=\frac{H(s)}{1-H(s)}=\frac{\omega_n^2}{D(s)-\omega_n^2}=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s(s+2\zeta\omega_n)}\tag{3}$$
The phase margin $\Delta\phi$ is the difference between the actual phase $\phi(\omega)$ of $G(j\omega)$ and $-\pi$, evaluated at the crossover frequency $\omega_c$ for which $|G(j\omega)|$ equals $1$, i.e.,
$$\Delta\phi=\pi+\phi(\omega_c)\tag{4}$$
Let's first determine the crossover frequency $\omega_c$. From $(3)$ with $s=j\omega_c$ we have
$$|G(j\omega_c)|^2=\frac{\omega_n^4}{\omega_c^2(\omega_c^2+4\zeta^2\omega_n^2)}=1\tag{5}$$
which yields
$$\left(\frac{\omega_c^2}{\omega_n^2}\right)^2+4\zeta^2\frac{\omega_c^2}{\omega_n^2}-1=0\tag{6}$$
with the solution
$$\frac{\omega_c^2}{\omega_n^2}=\sqrt{4\zeta^4+1}-2\zeta^2\tag{7}$$
For the phase $\phi(\omega_c)$ at the crossover frequency we obtain from $(3)$ (again by setting $s=j\omega_c$)
$$\phi(\omega_c)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega_c}{2\zeta\omega_n}\right)\tag{8}$$
With $(4)$ and $(7)$ we finally obtain for the phase margin
\begin{align*}
\Delta\phi &= \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{4\zeta^4+1}-2\zeta^2}}{2\zeta}\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{4+1/\zeta^4}-2}}{2}\right) \\
&= \arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\sqrt{4+1/\zeta^4}-2}}\right) \\
&= \arctan\left(2\zeta\sqrt{\sqrt{4\zeta^4+1}+2\zeta^2}\right)\tag{9}
\end{align*}
where I've used $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$.

Thank you! I was working on exactly doing this, as Dan suggested I will change the mark to this answer.

This comes about from the denominator of the transfer function which is the "Characteristic Equation". Showing this in Laplace in the 2nd order Canonical Form we get:
$$H(s) = \frac{w_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}$$
With:
$\omega_n$: natural frequency 
$\zeta$: damping factor
Note how plotting the roots of the denominator on the S-plane, for $\zeta<1$ will result in two complex poles with the radius to the poles as given by $\omega_n$ and the angle $\theta$ from the negative real axis given by the inverse cosine of $\zeta$.

Why that is becomes more intuitive if you consider the polar values for the two poles, writing the denominator equation $D(s)$ with the two poles $p_1, p_1^*$ as:
$$D(s) = (s-p_1)(s-p_1^*)  = (s + \omega_n e^{-j\theta})(s + \omega_n e^{j\theta})$$
$$= s^2 +  \omega_n (e^{j\theta} + e^{-j\theta}) + \omega_n^2$$
And using Euler's formula $2\cos(\theta)= e^{j\theta} + e^{-j\theta}$ results in:
$$D(s) = s^2 + 2\omega_n cos(\theta) + \omega_n^2$$
Take-aways for a 2nd order system:

The cosine of the angle, $\theta$ to the pole is the damping ratio $\zeta$ (for all damping ratios <=1)
The magnitude of the vector to the pole is the natural frequency $\omega_n$
The imaginary part of the pole as $\pm w_n\sin(\theta)$ is the damped frequency $\omega_d$, The damped frequency $\omega_d$ is the actual oscillation frequency in the response, which is always less than (but could be very close to) the natural frequency.
The real part of the pole is $\omega_n \cos(\theta)$ which equals $\omega_n \zeta$ is proportional to the inverse of the settling time  $(4/(\omega_n \zeta)$ is the 2% settling time)
Higher order systems are reasonably approximated by this 2nd order response if there are two dominant poles (dominant means closest to the $j\omega$ axis) with the other poles sufficiently (~ 10x or more) further away.
The closer the pole is to the $j\omega$ axis, the lower the damping factor, the faster the rise/fall time, and the greater the overshoot and ringing (damping factor approaches 0). This would mean less phase margin and greater chance for instability.
The closer the pole is to the real axis, the higher the damping factor and less overshoot and slower rise/ fall time (damping factor approaches 1). This would mean more phase margin and less chance for instability (guaranteed stable if we know the pole will stay in the left half plane), but not ideal in terms of rise/fall time for a given natural frequency.
A damping factor of 0.7 (pole is equidistant from $j\omega$ and real axis) is often chosen as the best compromise between rise and fall time and overshoot and ringing.

If this is helpful, please check out my online course "DSP for Software Radio" routinely offered through https://dsprelated.com/courses (one session is starting this week!) and  https://ieeeboston.org/courses/ where I go through all this in great detail (radio receivers have a ton of control loops in them so we cover all this in a very practical way) .

Thank you very much, you made my day.

@phionez I’m glad it was helpful to you!

Hi Dan, this is all correct and well explained, but wasn't the question specifically about the phase margin of a second-order system? Maybe it's just me, because the OP seems to be happy ... :)

@phionez I agree with Matt - I think you should switch the checkmark to his as although my answer is helpful / tutorial, I never did answer your question! I think his answer would make your day as well!

@DanBoschen I asked for where to start, because I remember now from that basic setup how to derive it myself, and I was going to add my own complete answer in a couple of days after reading some more. Thank you both very much
